# Finding biggest integer smaller than max key but not in AVL tree

Tags: rank, avl-tree

Given AVL tree T, I need to find the maximal integer which is smaller than maximal key in tree, but is not in tree.

I've written auxiliary functions to get the biggest node, yet my thoughts are stuck.

I tried looking at the rank of the maximal node and the rank of it's successor yet that doesn't do any help.

Any ideas would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is: initialize a variable `crawl` with the `max` (`crawl <- max`). Search the second maximum. If it's smaller than `crawl-1`, your answer is `crawl-1`. Else, there are two possibilities:

1. The second maximum is equal to `crawl-1`: assign `crawl <- crawl-1`.
2. The second maximum is equal to `crawl`.

In any of the cases, search the third maximum. If it's smaller than `crawl-1`, your answer is `crawl-1`. Else, there are two possibilities:

1. The third maximum is equal to `crawl-1`: assign `crawl <- crawl-1`.
2. The third maximum is equal to `crawl`.

...

Did you notice the recursion structure ?

Either you will find the answer at some step or you will achieve the smallest element without answer. In this case the answer will be `crawl-1` (which will store `min-1` at this step).

To find the successive maximums, you can iteratively remove the maximum. For example, to find the second maximum, remove the maximum and find the maximum in the new AVL tree.

The time complexity would be `O(n * log n)`. Each removal operation takes `O(log n)` and you do at most `n` removals.

Comment: This is a good solution, however it is not the most optimal.

I've been able to solve this within O(nlogn) , yet according to colleagues, the wanted time complexity is O(logn).

I think it has something to do with the fact that we know the index of maximal node in the sorted array, since we can find the rank of every node in O(logn).

Comment: Can I consider that I already have the sorted array that originated the AVL tree? What about its values? Are they all distinct ? Do they have an upper bound and a lower bound ?

Comment: We dont have any upper/lower bounds in terms of key values, number of nodes.
all values are distinct, insert was built so already existing values are not duplicated.
Even though we dont have the sorted array (would take O(n) time to make), we can get the rank (index of node in sorted arr) in O(logn) time using auxiliary function.
values are all positive integers, including zero.

Comment: Good! I will add a detailed answer of the O(log n) approach for this case  =) But I will keep the other answer, because I think it's the best complexity for the generic case where you only the AVL tree and you don't have any constraints in the node values.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the rank array and all values are distinct (`n` values), we can do a binary search like the following:

If `max - min + 1 = n`, the answer is `min-1`.

Else, take the median element of [min, max] in the tree.

1. `max - med + 1 = n/2`. In this case, consider that the element right before `med` is `med_before`. If `med_before < med - 1`, the answer is `med - 1`. Else, go to `[min, med_before]`.
2. `max - med + 1 > n/2`. In this case, consider that the element right after `med` is `med_after`. Go to `[med_after, max]`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time accessing med_before and med_after; i found a getMedian that works in O(logn) and added it to my code, however I am not sure how to access the nodes before and after, Im considering adding a getByRank function to get a node by its rank, but i'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: I think in the conditions of your problem, if you remove the max, the median of the resulting tree is med_before of the original tree and if you remove the min, the median of the resulting tree is med_after of the original tree.

Comment: I see how you meant to find med_before/after, the thing I'm having a hard time is calling the function with a specific range, the func given declaration is `int last_missing(AVLNodePtr root)` what would you recommend on doing in this situation?

Comment: I believe in our case, the intervals we fall in during the binary search always correspond to a subtree of a node in the original AVL tree. So we can always identify an interval by the root of its corresponding subtree. This fact needs to be explored somehow.

Comment: assuming the median is not the root, it's either right son of root or the most far right node in left subtree of root, if we're on the second case, i cannot call the function with median's right subtree (which will be null), and it's left subtree is not the whole group of nodes that are smaller than the median in said case, that's where i'm having a hard time.

Comment: In the case the median is the most far right node in left subtree of root, I believe the left interval [min, med_before] would correspond to the left subtree of the root without the median and the right interval [med_after, max] would correspond to the root plus its right subtree.